# Get JSON Object after submit the form in phonegap

Tags: android, html, forms, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm new in phonegap development in android.
i'm working on phonegap application. I have subbmited the code on the server using the form tag. Now i want to get the result back. So please hlep me how to get the result which is returned by the server. the result is in the form of JSON.

Here is my code that i'm using to submit the form in my html file.

```
    <form id="signUpform" action="http://web1.xxx.com/sss/signup.php" method="post" 
    onsubmit="return( validate() );">
    <div style="float:left; width: 100%; height: inherit;">
        <h3>New Client</h3>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div style="float:left; width: 80%; height: inherit; margin-top: 5px;">
        <div style="float:left; width: 40%; height: inherit; margin-top: 5px; padding-top: 8px;">
             <label>UserName </label></div>
        <div style="float:right; width: 60%; height: inherit;">
            <input id="UserUsername" type="text" name="username" /></div>
    </div>
    <br />  
    <div style="float:left; width: 80%; height: inherit; margin-top: 5px;">
        <div style="float:left; width: 40%; height: inherit; margin-top: 5px; padding-top: 8px;">
            <label>Password </label></div>
        <div style="float:right; width: 60%; height: inherit;">
            <input id="pass" type="text" name="password" /></div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div style="float:left; width: 80%; height: inherit; margin-top: 5px;;">
        <div style="float:left; width: 40%; height: inherit; margin-top: 5px; padding-top: 8px;">
            <label>   Confirm Password </label></div>
        <div style="float:right; width: 60%; height: inherit;">
            <input id="cpass" type="text" name="confirm_password" /></div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div style="vertical-align:middle; float:left; width: 80%; height: inherit; margin-top: 5px;">
        <div style="float:left; width: 40%; height: inherit; margin-top: 5px; padding-top: 8px;">
            <label> Email ID </label></div>
        <div style="float:right; width: 60%; height: inherit;">
            <input id="UserEmail" type="text" name="email" /></div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div style="float:left; width: 80%; height: inherit; margin-top: 5px;">
        <div style="float:right; width: 100%; height: inherit;">
            <input type="submit" value="Get Started"/> </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

form is submited on the server. and i get back the result in JSON fromat.
Result is :

```
{"UserID":"220"}
```

this will print on the device after i submitted the form.

So please help me how i can get this value.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please go through this link it may help you http://samcroft.co.uk/2012/posting-data-from-a-phonegap-app-to-a-server-using-jquery/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var urlStr = URL1 + "username=" + username + "&password=" + password;

 jQuery.support.cors = true;
 $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     crossDomain: true,
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     url: urlStr,
     data: "{}",
     dataType: "json",
     timeout: 5000,
     success: ajaxCallSucceed,
     error: ajaxCallFailed
 });

function ajaxCallSucceed(json){
 //  success
 }

function ajaxCallFailed(json){
 // failed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
      jQuery.ajax({
                    url : MyPostUrl,
                    type : "GET",
                    dataType : "json",
                    success : function(resultvalue) {

                        var val = JSON.stringify(resultvalue);
                        for ( var i = 0; i < resultvalue.Result.length; i++) {
                            finalresult = resultvalue.Result[i].result;
                            //alert(finalresult);
          //u can get your value here.
          //u need to use this loop to get value.
          //As it gives here {"result":"1"}
          //If your  "userID" is within "result" in json.Then u need to set another loop here.else just replace "result" with your "userID" key at (resultvalue.Result[i].result;). 
                        }
                        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();


                    },
                    error : function(e) {
                        //navigator.notification.alert("Request Failed.Please check Net connection");
                        navigator.notification.confirm(
                                'Request Failed.Please check Net connection', // message
                                alertDismissed, // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
                                'Title', // title
                                'OK' // buttonLabels
                        );

                        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
                    }

                });
```

Answer (score 1):

To send a request to remote server use **jQuery.ajax**

Sample code is

```
function FetchData() {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: "Your_URL",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {


            $.each(data, function (i, object) {
                alert(obj.Data);
            });

        },
        error: function () {
            alert("There was an error loading the feed");
        }
    });
}
```

Call this function `onclick` of your button.

Hope that helps.